# How do I build an os.system() command using a Path object + string?

Tags: python, concatenation, os.system

I'm trying to write a script that pulls in some paths from a config file and invokes the system shell to run a command using the path as part of the command.  It's basically a digest script that unrars all files in a directory.  Please keep in mind, I am teaching myself Python, this is my first python script and this is my first post.  Please excuse any mistakes in etiquette on my part.

The goal is to get the command 'C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe x' to run on a directory.  Unfortunately, I've learned that Python doesn't let you concatenate a string to a Path object, presumably because they are two different element types.  I have the following:

In config file:

```
[Paths]
WinrarInstallPath = C:\Program Files\WinRAR\
NewFilesDirectory = M:\Directory\Where\Rar Files\Are\Located
```

Script:

```py
**SOME CODE***
new_files_dir = Path(config.get('Paths', 'NewFilesDirectory'))
winrar_dir = Path(config.get('Paths', 'WinrarInstallPath'))

**SOME MORE CODE**
os.chdir(new_files_dir)
for currentdir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    os.system(winrar_dir + "rar.exe x " + os.getcwd() + currentdir[1:] + '\\*.rar')
```

Which gives me the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'"

I've tried

```py
os.system(str(winrar_dir) + "rar.exe x " + os.getcwd() + currentdir[1:] + '\\*.rar')
```

but it doesn't handle the spaces in the directory names.  I've also tried

```py
os.system(os.path.join(winrar_dir, "rar.exe x ") + os.getcwd() + currentdir[1:] + '\\*.rar')
```

with the same result

I realize I can treat it as a string from the beginning and do the following

```py
wrd = config.get('Paths', 'WinrarInstallationPath')
winrar_dir = '"' + wrd + '"'

os.system(winrar_dir + "rar.exe x " + os.getcwd() + currentdir[1:] + '\\*.rar')
```

but Python has been pretty slick so far and this just feels very clumsy, so I feel like I'm missing something, but I haven't been able to find an answer so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `os.system`. Use `subprocess.call`:

```
os.system(winrar_dir + "rar.exe x " + os.getcwd() + currentdir[1:] + '\\*.rar')
```

The list is literally what the argv array is. No need to quote for the shell.

```
subprocess.call([os.path.join(winrar_dir, 'rar.exe'), 'x', os.getcwd(), os.path.join(currentdir[1:], '*.rar')])
```

You might also see that I am not fond of the pathlib module. I used its predecessor path and only found its walkfiles method useful.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!  This worked very well once I straightened out a couple of logic errors that had nothing to do with your suggestion.  For posterity, here is what I finally came up with `rar_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + ".rar"` just to make things more readable and `subprocess.call([os.path.join(winrar_dir, "rar.exe"), "x", os.path.join(new_files_dir, os.path.join(currentdir, rar_name))])`

Comment: Don't need to nest `os.path.join` calls: `os.path.join(new_files_dir, currentdir, rar_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to try to add to a `pathlib.Path` object you need to add its `joinpath` method to add to the path rather that just the `+` operator as you would use with strings (that's what's giving you the `TypeError`).

```
# From the docs:
Path('c:').joinpath('/Program Files')
Out[]: PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files')
```

If you're still having trouble test that the paths you're reading in are pointing to the right place by using the `Path.exists()` method or `Path.glob` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Right, ok, makes sense.  But at the end of the day it seems no matter what I do it's going to pass C:\Program Files... into the os.system command and the shell is going to interpret that as me trying to start a program called Program with an argument of Files.  In this case maybe it will be easier to handle the formatting while I'm generating the config file and pull in the parameters as strings?

Comment: You just need to put quotes into the system call.  Something like this would work: `os.system('''"{}" "{}"'''.format(winrar_path, working_dir_path)`.  Also, maybe consider the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: it's-yer-boy-chet: There's no reason to use triple `'''` quotes in that, singles would work just as well.

Comment: @it's-yer-boy-chet - thank you very much.  I went with your and Dan D.'s suggestion to use the subprocess module.  See below if interested.